# Bootstrap Example Stacked-to-horizontal not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have read the other post and made sure that my index.html is in the same folder as my css,fonts and js folders but it still will not render properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please explain your issue in detail, what exactly is not working? have you made sure Bootstrap's files are being loaded properly? you can open your browser's console and any error while including a file will be listed there

Comment: All i see are the .col-md-8 and .col-md-4, it does not generate the resizing bar that appears on the example or in jfiddle

Comment: generate the gray resizing bar*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Bootstrap doesn't tell you on their page but the shading of each cell is not a default feature. If you inspect the element using chrome you will see an additional css rule. So this is how you do it:

1) change the classes from "row" to "row show-grid" in your index html.

2) create the following rule in your css style sheet:

```
.show-grid [class^="col-"] {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
```

3) run your code

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache. And mostly read get started at Getbootstrap.com as you are on the correct path.

Comment: I have read the get started section and clearing the cache did not help

Comment: The bar is css driven which means you are missing a class. What jsfiddle example are you referring to? Please provide more details as we obviously can't read your mind! Lol! Jk.

Answer (score -1):

Install bootstrap properly using Bootstrap CDN [Get Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)